# Code-First generated database different from DbContext Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design, ef-code-first

I've successfully setup a simple MVC4 internet app that stores  model data onto a LocalDb v11.0 SQL server. I generated the database using a code-first approach, however, the Table fields in the database are different than the model database context.

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlantLocation { get; set; }
    public Plant PlantType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Plant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class RecordContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Plant> Plants { get; set; }
}

dbo.Records Table 
[Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[PlantLocation] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Description]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
**[PlantType_Id]  INT            NULL,**
```

When i pull-up the table data, every field is populated correctly, with the PlantType_ID showing the Id of the selected Plant.

- How am i supposed to used the PlantType_ID to display the ID of the Plant(or even use this stored data) in my View if PlantType_ID is not in my RecordContext?

I have tried the following to try an get at the ID but to no avail:

```
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlantType.Id)
```

I'm not getting build errors or runtime errors if anyone is wondering. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `virtual` to the plant property to allow lazyloading:

```
public virtual Plant PlantType { get; set; }
```

To avoid [N+1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/08/18/select-n-1-problem-how-to-decrease-your-orm-performance.aspx) issues, you can instruct EF to bring back the PlantType record as part of the same initial query.  Something like:

```
var record = db.Records.Include("PlantType").First();
```

We have an extension method to make it a little nicer using lambdas:

```
var record = c.Records.Include(i => i.PlantType).First();

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path) where T : class
    {
        return System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include(source, path);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Alternatively you could add the following property to the Record model if all you are after is the id:

```
public int PlantTypeId { get; set; }
```

Your database structure will largely stay the same (constraint names will change) except now you can change your razor syntax to be:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlantTypeId)
```

You do not need to add the `include` comments now either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the plant name, you could directly use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlantType.Name)
```

Comment: Sorry, i meant the ID. In my database, PlantType_ID =5 (for example). whenever i access PlantType.Name in my viewmodel, they are null. PlantType_ID is not a property of any of my classes yet it appears in my database as a value in the Record table. How can i use this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using primary key for display for. That's why its not showing as above said you can use display for for plant type name and other fields.

Comment: This is my Index controller : return View(db.Records.ToList()); Simply doing DisplayFor(...PlantType.Id(..or Name)) are both null, yet in the database i have PlantType_ID = 4.

Comment: Yes but why you need to display primary key ?

Comment: I am simply trying to access the plant stored in the database, but it is of type "plant", how can i grab this from the database?

Comment: display plant name with display for  and use primary key for any link or anything